# React setState cannot assign fileList instead assigns string of first fileName

Tags: html, reactjs, forms, submit, setstate

To begin with, I'm making a simple social media application. I'm trying to submit a form which has text, images, and videos. My frontend where the form is submitted is made with React and server is ran with node.js mounted on nginx. I was trying to append the inputted files into FormData with code below:

```
handleSubmit = function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("textBody", this.state.textBody)
    for (let i = 0; i < this.state.imgInput.length; i++) {
        formData.append("imgInput", this.state.imgInput.files[i], "img"+i.toString())
    fetch("mywebsite.com/api/submitArticle", {
        body: formData,
        method: "POST",
        credentials: 'include',
    }).then((response) => console.log(response))
    return false;
}.bind(this)

handleChange = function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (e.target.name === 'imgInput') {
        this.setState({
            imgInput: e.target.files,
            showSpan: false
        })
    }
}.bind(this)

<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <textarea id='textBody' name='textBody' onFocus={removeSpan} onBlur={checkSpanOn} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
        <input type="file" id="imgInput" name="imgInput" accept="image/*" ref={this.imgRef}  multiple={true} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
        <input type="submit" id="submitButton" name="submitButton" formEncType="multipart/form-data" />
</form>
```

But React gave me this error upon submitting the form:

```
TypeError: Failed to execute 'append' on 'FormData': parameter 2 is not of type 'Blob'.
```

at "formData.append("imgInput", this.state.imgInput.files[i], "img"+i.toString())".

So when I console logged what e.target.files before setState in handleChange, I got normal FileList with all the image files listed. But when I console loggedd this.state.imgInput after setState in handleChange, I got **String of C://fakepath/filename**, not fileList. (Initially state.imgInput was null. When I saw other examples and codes, e.target.files was fileList so I'm puzzled elsewhere I made mistake.

I was spending half my day on this problem and I'm 5 sec before fainting so any advice would be appreciated :) Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes this happening because the event is gone you need to store the event.target in variable  + the files will be in `imgInput` not `imgInput.files` so here it is:

```
   handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("textBody", this.state.textBody);
    for (let i = 0; i < this.state.imgInput.length; i++) {
      formData.append("imgInput", this.state.imgInput[i], "img" + i.toString());
       fetch("mywebsite.com/api/submitArticle", {
         body: formData,
         method: "POST",
         credentials: "include"
       }).then(response => console.log(response));
    }
  };

  handleChange = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const target = e.target;
    if (target.name === "imgInput") {
      this.setState(current => ({
        ...current,
        imgInput: target.files,
        showSpan: false
      }));
    }
  };
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but it still shows the same error... :Failed to execute 'append' on 'FormData': parameter 2 is not of type 'Blob'

Comment: i think i found what is missing is how you are getting the files from the state, please check updated answer.

Comment: Unfortunately it's the same error...do you feel the question needs any additional codes to answer?

Comment: here a full working example without error check it out https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-banzai-p0q6l?file=/src/App.js